# Passing a color through citymap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created a while loop that produces multiple predefined circles on Google Maps. Each circle is a different circle based on other predefined information. My problem is that when I create a key/value pair in citymap it won't pass through when I create the actual circle. Google debugger returns with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` wherever the `colors` is written. Here is the code.

This part is in a while loop.

```
  citymap["<?php echo ${'location_' . $e};?>"] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo ${'coordinates_' . $e};?>),
    population: <?php echo ${'radius_' . $e}; ?>,
    colors : <?php echo $color; ?>       
  };
```

And here is the code that constructs the circles.

```
    for (var city in citymap) {
      // Construct the circle for each value in a location.
      var populationOptions = 
      {
        strokeColor: citymap[city].colors,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: citymap[city].colors,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: citymap[city].population
      };
      cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably caused by the PHP part. View page source and see the js code produced by PHP and make sure that it is a valid JS array and doesn't have any syntax errors etc.

Comment: The php cide is correct. It works fine before I added the colors code to both `citymap` and the variable `populationOptions`. As for the page source code, the php variable `colors` is correctly outputted onto the javascript array.

Comment: Can you post a portion of that outputted code? Are you sure colors' value is in quotes like this: '#ffffff'?

Comment: Sorry, that was the problem. Didn't think you had to double quote the color id twice.